# PHP Local Website won't navigate away from index.php

Tags: php, html

I am building a PHP website in just the standard web tools and Xampp. I am NOT using wordpress. My PHP is working and I have set up my virtual hosts no problem. The issue is that Whenever i click a link to navigate to a different page (e.g. about.html or portfolio.phtml) it just reloads the index.php page.

My anchor tags all point to files in the directory and no matter the ending of the file, whether phtml, php or html, nothing happens. The page refuses to navigate away from home. I do not understand why this is happening. There's no point in me placing in a snip of code because it will not illustrate anything.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file? If so, post it.

Comment: Actually an example of the link tag would help, at least to rule out some things. Also, does the url change when you click a link?

Comment: Can u check if the case sensitivity in the links are correct? say your actual page is travel.php and in your link you have Travel.php?

Comment: I am not sure I do as I do not know where to find it. I presume I should have the standards. My website folder consists of very simple things like the php pages and others. @Ed Cottrell

Comment: While I don't see how it could help. Here:

<a href="about.phtml" alt="About"/>About Us</a>

Just a standard link. It was working before I incorporated PHP into my project. @Steve

Meghaa I checked the case sensitivity and its all the same. I doing everything lowercase at the minute.

Comment: @Icyfirefists It would be called `.htaccess`, and it would be in the root directory of your site.

Comment: Open chrome developer tools, click on the network tab, then click a link. You should see the http request to the server, and the response. If this is some redirect issue you should see a 302 response or similar. Without actually having access to your local system its going to be very hard for anyone here to help debug this

Comment: Found the issue. Something I had typed wrong in mt httpd.conf file. Thanks so much everyone for your suggestions!